# MySQL Left Join Select all rows

Tags: mysql, php

Hi guys I have a query which is pulling data from database :

```
SELECT sandwich_table.id,
       `sandwich_name`,
       salad,
       COUNT(salad),
       salad_type.type,
       sandwich_type_table.type
FROM   `sandwich_table`
       LEFT JOIN urls
         ON sandwich_table.id = urls.sandwich_id
       LEFT JOIN salad_type
         ON urls.salad = salad_type.id
       LEFT JOIN sandwich_type_table
         ON `sandwich_table`.`sandwich_type` = sandwich_type_table.id
WHERE  `active` = 1
GROUP  BY sandwich_table.`id`,
          salad
```

Some of the data in salad_type.id is not represented in the `COUNT()`, as some types have not been established in the url table for example:

`salad_type.id` : 1,3 and 4 are in the url table but not 2.

I would like create a query to show all types whether there is a value or not? as this query only pulls the `salad_type.id` when it is established in the url table.

AS requested the table structures:

```
 CREATE TABLE `salad_type`
(
    `id` int(50) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment Primary Key,
    `type` varchar(255),
    `name` int(10) default NULL,
    `date` int(10) default NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `urls` 
    (
        id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `url` varchar(255) UNIQUE,
        `sandwich_id` int,
        `salad` int,
        `date_added` int,
        `username` int
    )
CREATE TABLE `sandwich_table` 
    (
        id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `sandwich_name` varchar(255) UNIQUE,
        `active` int,
        `sandwich_type` int,
        `username` int
    )
```

Comment: Required reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: Please supply the `CREATE TABLE` statements for all tables.

Comment: I see you've added some of them. What about `sandwich_type_table`?

Comment: Apologies i removed active by mistake. I have tried with INNER JOINS and still the only rows that appear are ones that have a count() that notes NULL

Comment: Also sandwich type is not part of the problem as the problem resides in the sald_type table